# How to get token from url in php with given path

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, authentication, token

this is the url and I want the value of token

```
http://localhost/#token=9d7813cfc4a6c8de7eghdgcf66990a064fd99796e621395b90df3723f73f03f32f49
```

Comment: Be very specific what you want, and what the situation is. For instance? Which language?(why did you add jquery and javascript to the tags and only mention php?)  Is the URL the script caller or just a string? Give an example of the code that you wrote yourself, what the result was, and what the desired result is. We can't guess. Your question is poly-interpretable and we are not here to program for you, we are here to help you if you run into problems while writing your  own program. Be very specific and post your code. Otherwise you will  get no help. Good luck.

Comment: Replace `#` with `?` in URL and use `$token = $_GET['token']`

Comment: Php only, I can not replace #

Comment: Do you have this full URL in string form then? Because if that is what the browser address bar shows, and you now want to get this value in the PHP script that was invoked by this URL: Not possible; the fragment portion of the URL does not get sent to the server in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below solutions

1 ) Replace # with ? in URL and use `$token = $_GET['token']`

2. If option 1 is not doable then can you below solution. I am assuming you have url in `$url` string
   convert into array by breaking from # then replace `token=`

   `$parts = explode ("#", $url); $token = str_replace("token=","",$parts[1]); echo $token;`